# cleaning an inspiron 500 m

Tags: laptop, cleaning, dell-inspiron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you clean your laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/134247/how-do-you-clean-your-laptop)

I have been running my inspiron 500 m in a very dusty (plaster dust) environment. I would like to remove the bottom cover and clean the filter etc. Can you help?